# SNAPT WAF Implementation

Tags: web-application-firewall

I just got the responsibility of implementing and managing the WAF for our SNAPT install. I have the WAF enabled on the Admin page for testing right now. I finally got an error so I can learn what the errors look like and how to fix them. So I need to put a URL exception in there. I followed the documentation and Naxis GitHub but when I put the [0-9]+ in the URL and click apply the system changes the "[]" to "_" then errors out. Now I can not delete the rule so I had to change it to just URL and blank. How do whitelist a URL "/some/267/thing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it is a bug in their code. I submitted for a fix.